# С какой буквы пишутся названия водоводов?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная, топонимика

Водовод северный, или водовод Западный, или водовод Стахановский?

Answer (score 1):

В географических и административно-территориальных названиях — названиях материков, морей, озер, рек, возвышенностей, гор, стран, краев, областей, населенных пунктов, улиц и т. п. — с прописной буквы пишутся все слова, кроме родовых понятий (остров, море, гора, область, провинция, улица, площадь и т. п.), служебных слов, а также слов *года, лет*, например:
*Большая Багамская банка, Днепровский лиман, Большой Барьерный риф.*

Слова, обозначающие участки течения рек, пишутся со строчной буквы, если не входят в состав названий, например:
*верхняя Припять, нижняя Березина*, но: *Верхняя Тура, Нижняя Тунгуска* (названия рек).

Чем же официальное **название водовода** (то есть [**топоним**](http://endic.ru/ozhegov/Toponim-35639.html)) — хуже?
Сравните: Венецианская лагуна, Обводный канал, Лебяжья канавка, Кронверкский проток.

Если слова «северный», «западный», «стахановский» входят в имя собственное, то есть в название водовода, они, конечно же, пишутся с прописной (большой) буквы, если же эти слова говорят только о месторасположении объекта, — со строчной (маленькой) буквы.
Вот, как мне кажется, неплохой пример:

> Петергофская водоподводящая система, построенная в 1720-1721 годах, признана памятником культурного наследия федерального значения. Она подводит воду в парки Петергофа с Ропшинских высот и состоит из трех ветвей — **в**осточной, **ц**ентральной и **з**ападной, включая восемь каналов, **Самсоновский** и **Нептуновский водоводы**, шесть шлюзов, 11 мостов, 18 каскадных прудов, ручьи и плотины.

[Географические и административно-территориальные названия](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/)
[Искусственные каналы Санкт-Петербурга](https://peterburg.center/ln/iskusstvennye-kanaly-sankt-peterburga-12-kanalov.html)